# when use copy_to_user, it gives bad address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to add a proc file to read some information from kernel. But when I try to `cat` the information from the proc file, it gives "bad address" error.

```
int proc_read(char *buffer, char **starter, off_t off, int count, 
              int *eof, void *data)
{

    if (off > 0)
    {
        *eof = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    if (copy_to_user(buffer, info_str, info_str_size))
    {
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return info_str_size;
}
```

After `insmod`, use `cat` to read the proc file, but gives the bad address error; `info_str` is a global `char` array.

Comment: seems ok, can you show the definition of info_str and info_str_size

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your problem is surprisingly simple. In `proc_read` functions you don't need to use `copy_to_user`: a simple `memcpy` will do the job, since the buffer lives in kernel memory. If you're creating a `proc_write` function, however, you do need to use `copy_from_user`, since in this case the buffer lives in user memory.

One tip is that you should also probably signal `EOF` on success. This will save your function from needing to be called twice.

The following should suffice:

```
int proc_read(char *buffer, char **starter, off_t off, int count,
              int *eof, void *data)
{
    if (off > 0)
    {
        *eof = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(buffer, info_str, info_str_size);
    *eof = 1;
    return info_str_size;
}
```

You should also note that this way of writing file entries is pretty old and you should probably avoid it. The `seq_file` interface is much less error prone (and will work with pagers like less and more). Take a look at http://lwn.net/Articles/22355/ if you're interested.